# Why is shuffle spill much larger than shuffle read or output size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a fairly simple PySpark job, in which the last stage reads in some shuffled data, performs some aggregation over a window, and writes to HDFS. The median task has:

1. 130 MB shuffle read
2. 3.4 MB output size (write to HDFS)
3. 2.0 GB shuffle spill (memory)
4. 140 MB shuffle spill (disk)

There is skew across tasks but nothing dramatic.

My question: since only 130 MB of shuffle was read per task, and there was no shuffle write (as there were no later stages), how could there possibly be 2 GB of shuffle spill per task?

My understanding is that shuffle data is spilled out of memory to disk if it takes up too much RAM on the executor. But here the amount that was spilled from memory was much larger than the total size of shuffled data. In general, how could shuffle spill be larger than the size of the shuffled data?

Comment: This question looks likely to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622577/understanding-huge-shuffle-spill-sizes-in-spark.